# Join Runing Sum in TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, join, left-join

I would like to join a running sum until a specific time point. E.g. I have two tables

Table A

```
TimestampOfInterest
2001-01-01
2001-02-01
2001-03-01
```

Table B

```
Timestamp    Credits
2001-01-01   1
2001-01-05   1
2001-02-10   1
2001-03-15   1
```

Joining B -> A should lead to

```
TimestampOfInterest Credits
2001-01-01          0
2001-02-01          2
2001-03-01          3
```

That is the sum of credits until the given TimestampOfInterest.

Can someone help?
Lazloo

Comment: Just join the rows and aggregate. What have you tried? Where have you got stuck?

Comment: joining(and therefore expanding the number of rows) and aggregating is not that performant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

not sure you need join. You can simply do this:

```
Select TimestampOfInterest, 
     (Select SUM(Credits) 
     from TableB 
     where Timestamp < A.TimeStampOfInterest and Category = A.Category) Credits
From TableA A
```

Comment: Good idea, I just realized that I did not mention that the table has an additional column "category" and the sum needs to be grouped by the category. As a consequence, the resulting table would look something like 

TimestampOfInterest Credits Category
2001-02-01          1             A
2001-02-01          2             B
2001-03-01          2             A
2001-03-01          3             B

Comment: I have added something to the subquery to take category into account.

Comment: A correlated subquery *is* a type of join